# Geo Fix Not Setting Browser Location in Android Emulator

Tags: android, geolocation, android-emulator

Using the the Geo Fix command to set the virtual device's location in the Android Emulator works properly for the Maps application.  However, when I attempt to view my current location in Google Maps in the virtual device's browser, I receive the "Your location could not be determined" error.  Does the Geo Fix command not support the W3C geolocation standard or am I missing something?

Comment: I have this exact problem too. I'd be very interested in an answer, as I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. What is wrong exactly?

Answer (score -1):

(1) First, open the emulator, then run cmd, type telnet localhost 5554 
    this will appear
    Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
    OK.

(2) geo fix Latitude Longitude

(3) `Location loc = LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");`

if it doesn't help,try this:

open eclipse, windows -> open perspective -> DDMS -> Emulator control -> Manual to manually set the latitude and longitude, and press the send button.

good luck~